# Custom Alert dialog is not getting dismissed on click of a button and showing a white background below the custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I created a custom alert dialog to show in my app. It has an imageView, two textViews and a button. I am trying to show this custom alert dialog once my main activity launches.I am calling this custom alert dialog.show() in a separate method according to my requirement.The custom alert dialog is showing up but on click of a button it is not getting dismissed, also the custom alert dialog is showing a extra white background.

**showCustomAlertDialog() Method**

```
 public void showCustomAlertDialog() {
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
 final View promptView  =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_alert_dialog, null);
 final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

 Button recordButton = (Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.record_button);
 recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Dismiss the dialog");
        builder.dismiss();
     }
  });
  builder.setView(promptView);
  builder.show();
 }
```

**reminder_alert_dialog Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_alert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/greetings_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GOOD MORNING, KEVIN"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/medicines_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Have you taken your medicines today?"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_below="@id/greetings_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/record_button"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#3BC4B8"
    android:text="Record"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@id/medicines_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming to the extra white background, you have to apply the Window Background colour to transparent for the AlertDialog with this code

```
Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
alertDialog.show();
```

And the issue where dialog isn't showing, is the `System.out.println()` called? I would also recommend you setting the view for the AlertDialog.Builder before setting the listeners like,

```
final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

  builder.setView(promptView);

 Button recordButton = (Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.record_button);
 recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Dismiss the dialog");
        builder.dismiss();
     }
  });
```

Comment: alertDialog and builder are two different variables right. I want both alertDilaog and builder in a single card, but I don't see any place where you are passing alertDilaog as parameter to builder.

Comment: Here in the code, I've mentioned `builder` is actually of `AlertDialog` type. Builder is used for building. If you want an `AlertDialog.Builder` type, don't call `create()` method, so code will be `new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
//class variables
 AlertDialog dialog;
 Button dismiss;
//Add your other views if required

//in onCreate() activity method
makeDialog();

//makeDialog() method code

void makeDialog(){
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("Title");
      View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
      dismiss = root.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
      //another views initialization goes here...
      dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       //your logic or job...
      });
      builder.setView(root);
      dialog = builder.create();
}
```

finally show the dialog whenever you want

```
dialog.show();
```